# Object returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, this

If I call the find function APP.count() all is ok I am getting the correct result but when I call APP.add() I getting this.basket is undefined. I don't get why this is happening?

```
var APP = (function() {

  var
    basket = [
      { id: 100, price: 10, description: '', name: 'item one', quantity: 10, url: '' },
      { id: 200, price: 20, description: '', name: 'item two', quantity: 15, url: '' }
    ],

    find = function(item) {
      for(var i = 0; i < this.basket.length; i++) {
        if(this.basket[i].id === item) {
          return i
        }
      }
      return null
    },

    add = function(item) {
      var itemFound = find(item)
    },

    count = function() {
      var total = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < this.basket.length; i++) {
        total = total + this.basket[i].quantity
      }
      return total
    };

  return {
    basket: basket,
    find: find,
    add: add,
    count: count
  };

})();

 APP.count()      /* works */
 APP.add()        /* returns this.basket as undefined */
```

Comment: Edited. you have to call `this.find(item)` instead of `find(item)` I guess

Comment: Thanks that did work but I don't get how basket not a property of APP?

Comment: I edited my comment because I did not see that the function was returning an object with same properties,  both would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from the call of `find(item)` in the `add` function.

Calling `find` function like that will not use the context of `APP` object as `this`, so `this.basket` will be undefined.

You can check what is the current context `this` with a simple `console.log(this)`

So if you want to call the `find` function with the context of APP, in the `add` function you need to call `this.find(item)`

Answer (score 0):

Hi the issue is with the **this** reference when you call find method by  add()

```js
add = function(item) {
      var itemFound = find(item)
    },
```

**this keyword is referring the window object**

try with this below is the running code

```js
var APP = (function() {

  var
    basket = [
      { id: 100, price: 10, description: '', name: 'item one', quantity: 10, url: '' },
      { id: 200, price: 20, description: '', name: 'item two', quantity: 15, url: '' }
    ],

    find = function(item) {
      for(var i = 0; i < this.basket.length; i++) {
        if(this.basket[i].id === item) {
          return i
        }
      }
      return null
    },

    add = function(item) {
      var itemFound = this.find(item) //changed
      return itemFound;                //changed
    },

    count = function() {
      var total = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < this.basket.length; i++) {
        total = total + this.basket[i].quantity
      }
      return total
    };

  return {
    basket: basket,
    find: find,
    add: add,
    count: count
  };

})();
```